# Newbie SQL joining question: houses, refrigerators, and apples

Tags: sql

There are three tables in my database: apples, refrigerators, and houses. Each apple belongs to a refrigerator (it has a column that references the refrigerator that it's in), and each refrigerator belongs to a house. The problem is, each apple ALSO belongs to a house. I guess this isn't "normalized" or whatever, but it's the way it is.

Obviously, each apple should belong to the house that its refrigerator belongs to. An apple can't be in two different places at once, after all.

So, my question is this: what SQL statement will allow me to find all of the "bad apples" that for some reason incorrectly reference a different house than the refrigerator that they are supposedly in. In other words, I need to find the apples that contain contradictory information.

I don't know if this is a "join" question or not, but I'm sure there's probably a very straightforward way of figuring this out. I just don't know what it is. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So the relationship is based on a `parent_ownership` column in the `APPLES` table?

Comment: Why isn't it normalized? The obvious but annoying answer would be "normalize your tables so you don't have this problem."

Comment: Well, seeing that my job is to "fix it", one of the things I have to do is find the bad data and make sure the apples are put in their correct places.

Comment: I had a good chuckle on the 'bad apples' bit, thx for that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select a.*
   from apples a 
   inner join refrigerators r
   on a.refrigeratorid = r.refrigeratorid
   where a.houseid != r.houseid
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM apples a
INNER JOIN fridge f
ON f.appleID = a.appleID
WHERE a.houseID <> f.houseID
```

Of course, this is a bad schema design, but you seem to know that already.

Comment: I think 'house' doesn't have an 'appleID' column

Comment: You have this backwards.  House is not going to have an AppleID - instead Apple should have a HouseID.

Answer (score 1):

This will help you: [A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html). It's all there.